# What are the requirements for a key in an NSDictionary?

Tags: cocoa-touch, nsdictionary

I have the need to uses custom class that I wrote as a key in an `NSMutableDictionary` (A `Socket` class, in this case.)

In Java when I use a `HashMap` or `TreeMap`, the object requires either a hash function or comparator function respectively for the dictionary to operate. In general, dictionaries need to know some way to compare keys.

From what I've read in the documentation, it doesn't look like I have to do this to use `NSMutableDictionary` though. Is that correct? And if it is, does anyone know how they implemented key comparison?

Comment: [Collections Programming Guide -> Dictionaries -> Using Custom Keys](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Dictionaries.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000134-SW8)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as the key conforms to `NSCopying` (which `NSObject` does not, but many things do), it can be used as a key. The key will be copied using `copyWithZone:`.

Regarding how this works, it works just as you note in Java. "The object requires either a hash function or comparator function respectively for the dictionary to operate." Every `NSObject` implements both `hash` and `isEqual:`.

Answer (score 4):

Default implementation of the -hash is based on the object's instance address, so it may be a bad option for you to use as key in NSDictionary. So by default two logically-equal instances of your class will map to two different entries in the dictionary until you properly override **both** -isEqual and -hash to reflect your logic.

Apart from that you would absolutely **need** to properly override -copyWithZone: to also reflect your equality logic because NSDictionary copies it's keys.